# Convert SQL Query to Hive Query

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql

Can some one assist me to convert this `SQL` query into `hive` to get same output ?

Below is the query

```
select count(email), 
       case substring_index(email,"@",-1) 
           when 'gmail.com'      then 'GMAIL' 
           when 'googlemail.com' then 'GMAIL' 
           when 'yahoo.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
           when 'ymail.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
            else 'OTHER' 
       END as DOMAIN  
   from DATA1 group by 2;
```

Comment: I am just having emails in a table and after executing above query I am getting below output .. I need same output in hive as well . Please suggest me the query in hive                                                                                                                           
  .+--------------+--------+
| count(email) | DOMAIN |
+--------------+--------+
|            3 | GMAIL  |
|            2 | OTHER  |
|            3 | YAHOO  |
+--------------+--------+

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Please use edit option of your post and put the relevant code snippets in Question description. Do not post question details in comments section due to character limit and lesser readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(email), 
       case split(email,'@')[1] 
           when 'gmail.com'      then 'GMAIL' 
           when 'googlemail.com' then 'GMAIL' 
           when 'yahoo.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
           when 'ymail.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
            else 'OTHER' 
       end as DOMAIN  
   from DATA1 
  group by 
    case substring_index(email,"@",-1) 
       when 'gmail.com'      then 'GMAIL' 
       when 'googlemail.com' then 'GMAIL' 
       when 'yahoo.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
       when 'ymail.com'      then 'YAHOO' 
       else 'OTHER' 
     end;
```

Read about [group by position syntax](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+GroupBy) and apply accordingly to your hive version if you want `group by 2` to work.

Comment: Thank You . I have tried by  replacing sub string with split function in hive . It is working

Comment: @Deepthi Please do not forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied